# Is it possible to find the source of website data?

Tags: database, web

When a website is constantly updating it's information from a data source, is it possible to find out what or where that data source is?

An example of what I'm talking about is stock prices. I'm curious to learn for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the site has implemented the solution. If it's server-side, you probably won't be able to find out. If it's in javascript, you could find out by looking at the page sources, such as in Chrome -> Inspect. But you'll need to know your way around.